# Superfish Mobile Navigation Menu

Tags: mobile, navigation, superfish

I have got this version http://jsfiddle.net/6vp3U/

```
   $('#mobnav-btn').click(

function () {
    $('.sf-menu').toggleClass("xactive");


});


$('.mobnav-subarrow').click(

function () {
    $(this).parent().toggleClass("xpopdrop");


});
```

of a Superfish menu that scales to a mobile version working ok, and I have positioned the mobile menu at the top of the page and it appears when it is scaled down to 800px.

Only thing is when I click on the menu button, the menu appears below all of my header content. Is their a way to make the menu when clicked on to push all other content down and show the menu?

Hope that makes sense.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

[Your Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6vp3U/425/)

```
<div id="nav">...</div>

#nav {
width: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks but this does not work for me, is it becaue my navigation (sf-menu) starts after all of my header content?

Comment: If you want your navigation above your content, you must write it first in your sourcecode.

Or you have to poition it absolute. But then it will overlay you content. The only other thing i added is a container including your nav and giving it 100% width. SO the content will be eblow your nav and not aside.